# How to render my Modal window and all the information contained inside ( in React)?

Tags: reactjs

My application renders twelve random people fetched from a different website. Everything works fine apart from my modal component(it should render more information about the person you clicked). For some reason whenever I try to render it I get this error 'Modal.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'medium' of undefined' and more errors comes with it. I am printing props.modalInfo from the Modal component to the console and it does have all the information I need, but for some reasons it shows that props.modalInfo is undefined when I try to render it. I have never done modal box in React (I am a beginner). Could someone explain me how I can render my Modal and pass all the data successfully? Thank you in advance!

```
    handleClick(id) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            const modalInfoToPass = prevState.employeeList.filter(employee => 
               {
                if(`${employee.name.first} ${employee.name.last}` === id){
                    // get only and only one object that fulfils the 
                    // condition
                    return employee;
                }
            })
            return {
                displayModal: true,
                // update the modalInfo state
                modalInfo: modalInfoToPass

            }
        })  
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <Header />
                <main>
                    {
                        this.state.loading ? <h2 className='load-page'>Loading...</h2> : 
                        this.state.employeeList.map(employee => 
                            <Employee key={`${employee.name.title}
                             ${employee.name.last}`} 
                             employeeInfo={employee}
                             **handleClick={this.handleClick}**
                             />)
                    }
                </main>
                <Footer />
                **{this.state.displayModal && <Modal modalInfo={this.state.modalInfo} />}**
            </div>
        );
    }
```

---

```
function Modal(props) {
    **console.log(props.modalInfo);**
    return (
        <div className='bg-modal'>
            <div className='modal-content'>
                <div className='modal-image'>
                    <img src={props.modalInfo.picture.medium} alt={`${props.modalInfo.name.title} ${props.modalInfo.name.first}`}/>
                </div>
                <div className='modal-info'>
                    <p className='name'>{props.modalInfo.name.first} {props.modalInfo.name.last}</p>
                    <p className='email'>{props.modalInfo.email}</p>
                    <p className='place'>{props.modalInfo.location.city}</p>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div className='modal-more-info'>
                    <p className='number'>{props.modalInfo.cell}</p>
                    <p className='address'>{`${props.modalInfo.location.street}, ${props.modalInfo.location.state}`}</p>
                    <p className='postcode'>{props.modalInfo.location.postcode}</p>
                    <p className='birthday'>{props.modalInfo.dob.date}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `id` and is it on an `employee`? If it isn't available, you could just pass what you're filtering for in your handleClick:

```
 handleClick={()=>this.handleClick(`${employee.name.first} ${employee.name.last}`)}
```

Or, you could just pass the employee:

```
handleClick={()=>this.handleClick(employee)}
```

and modify your handler:

```
handleClick(employee) {
    this.setState({modalInfo: employee,  displayModal: true})      
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot! I just passed 'onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.employeeInfo)}'  instead of this what I had previously 'onClick={() => props.handleClick(`${props.employeeInfo.name.first} ${props.employeeInfo.name.last}`)}' inside my Employee Component. I also didn't have to filter things out any more and it works! Thanks a lot. Idk why it is working this way and my previous way didn't want but I am glad the issue has been solved. . Thanks once more!